# Setting up orbited development environment on windows

Tags: python, orbited

I am developing a comet application using python orbited and django. But I don't know how to setup the development environment. Can any one please help me out? I looked at the documentations and tutorials... But I found them confusing... What I am looking is a walk-through kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can get you started - [Django, Orbited, Stomp and Co.](http://mischneider.net/?p=125)